# Swift 5 - Upload MultipartFormData Using Alamofire with Image from Gallery

Tags: ios, swift, multipartform-data, image-uploading

I try to upload image from gallery with several parameter to server but can't find any sample usefull because most of them are deprecated. don't know where to start.

```
func uploadImageAndData(){

       let periode = periodeField.text
       let kode_wilayah = kodeWilayahField.text
       let nama_petugas = namaPetugasField.text
       let upload_file = myImageView.image

        var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
        parameters = ["periode":periode,
                      "kode_wilayah":kode_wilayah,
                      "nama_petugas":nama_petugas,
                      "uploaded_file": upload_file] as [String : AnyObject]

        let URL = "myURL"

        Alamofire.upload(
            multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
                if let imageData = upload_file?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.3){
                    multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: self.myFileName)
                }
        }, to:URL)
        { (result) in
            switch result {
            case .success(let upload, _ , _):
                upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (progress) in    
                    //print("uploding")
                    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
                })  
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    debugPrint(response)
                    print("done")
                    print(response.result.value)   
                }    
            case .failure(let encodingError):
                print("failed")
                print(encodingError)  
            }
        }
    }
```

And this in from image picker function and no problem with choosing image from gallery.

```
@objc func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
myImageView.image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as! UIImage
            let data = image.pngData()! as NSData
            data.write(toFile: localPath!, atomically: true)
            let photoURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: localPath!) 
        }
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)  
    }
```

I can get the path but can't give it to upload function. I really appreciate for your help.

Comment: try https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519829/upload-image-to-server-using-alamofire

Comment: I dont understand with this part:
(imgData, withName: "fileset",fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
what should I fill if I use imagepicker?

Comment: In your case, you can use like (imageData, withName: "uploaded_file",fileName: "AnyName.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, i think this will help you.

```
    func imagupload(){
       let periode = periodeField.text
       let kode_wilayah = kodeWilayahField.text
       let nama_petugas = namaPetugasField.text
       let upload_file = myImageView.image

        var parameters = [String:AnyObject]()
        parameters = ["periode":periode,
                      "kode_wilayah":kode_wilayah,
                      "nama_petugas":nama_petugas,
                      "uploaded_file": upload_file] as [String : AnyObject]

        let URL = "myURL"


                        requestWith(endUrl: URL, imageData: myImageView.image!.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1.0), parameters: parameters, onCompletion: { (json) in
                            print(json)

                        }) { (error) in
                            print(error)

                        }
                    }


      func requestWith(endUrl: String, imagedata: Data?, parameters: [String : String], onCompletion: ((JSON?) -> Void)? = nil, onError: ((Error?) -> Void)? = nil){

        let url = endUrl


        let headers: HTTPHeaders = [

            "Content-type": "multipart/form-data"
        ]

        Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in
            for (key, value) in parameters {
                multipartFormData.append("\(value)".data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key as String)
            }

            if let data = imagedata{
                multipartFormData.append(data, withName: "imagename", fileName: "imagename.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            }

        }, to:url,headers: headers)
        { (result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let upload, _, _):
                upload.responseJSON { response in
                    let json : JSON = JSON(response.result.value)
                     print(json)
                    if let err = response.error{
                        onError?(err)

                        return
                    }
                    onCompletion?(json)

                }
            case .failure(let error):
               //print("Error in upload: \(error.localizedDescription)")
                onError?(error)

            }

        }

    }
```

only used imagupload function in whenever you use like,

```
self.imagupload()
```

Comment: i think, myimageview.image is null. please check it's null or not.