# 'Invalid type in JSON write (UIImage)' Alamofire API request

Tags: swift, uiimageview, alamofire

i am trying to send an image to an `api` using `alamofire` heres what i got:

```
var uploadedProfileImage: UIImage = UIImage()

let body: Parameters = [

          "profilePic": uploadedProfileImage,
          "name": "John Doe"
                  ]
Alamofire.request(BASE_URL",method: .post,parameters: body,encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseData { response in
                                                debugPrint("All Response Info: \(response)")

                                                if let data = response.result.value, let utf8Text = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
                                                    print("Data: \(utf8Text)")
                                                }
                                            }
```

so this is the code i am using `uploadProfileImage` has an image that the user picked from the library and my `api` receives a `json` body parameter in which it has profilePic which is off type file when i run this its giving me an error saying `'Invalid type in JSON write (UIImage)'`.theres is also a `terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException` error. what am i doing wrong and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't upload image with

```
"profilePic": uploadedProfileImage
```

as it's used for types that are encode-able such as strings , you need

[upload image to server using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519829/upload-image-to-server-using-alamofire)

```
func uploadImageAndData(_ url:String,parameters1:Parameters,headers1:HTTPHeaders,images:[UIImage]){


    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        // import image to request
        var i=0
        for imageData in images {
            //  multipartFormData.append(self.resizeImage(image: imageData, targetSize: CGSize(width: 400, height:
            multipartFormData.append(imageData.pngData()!, withName: "image", fileName: "image"+".jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
            i += 1


        }
        for (key, value) in parameters1 {
            multipartFormData.append((value as AnyObject).data(using: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!, withName: key)
        }
    } ,to: url,method:.post,
       headers:[:],

       encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.uploadProgress(closure: { (Progress) in
                print("Upload Progress: \(Progress.fractionCompleted)")
                //SwiftSpinner.show(progress: Progress.fractionCompleted*100, title: "تحميل")
            })
            upload.responseJSON { response in

                switch response.response?.statusCode {

                case 200 :


                    break

                case 400 :


                    break

                case 401 :


                    break


                case 302 :


                    break
                case 500 :


                    break

                default: break


                }

            }
            return
        case .failure(let encodingError):

        }

    })
}
```

---

```
    var head = [String:Any]()
    head["Accept"]="application/json"
    head["Authorization"] = "Bearer \(tokenIfExists)"
```

Comment: is there a possible solution?

Comment: ok i checked it out Thanks, i also have other variables in the parameters variables like names and everything can i also send those datas together using the upload method?

Comment: if you can maybe send a code snippet using my scenario i am new to swift

Comment: what kind of should i provide for the HttpHeader parameters?

Comment: Thank you for the support it really helped a lot, but i have a related question i have posted it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57521590/alamofire-sending-a-request-to-an-api-nsinvalidargumentexception i would really appreciate it if you can check it out.