# Assign different data and different length of items to a UICollectionView inside a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview

I have a category list and each category has a sub category say for example category one might have 10 subcategories and category two may have 5 subcategories.

I have implemented an UICollectionView inside an UITableView which works perfect but the only problem is how can I display the subcategories inside a particular Category
I have these classes
this is my `CategoriesCollection` class

```
class CategoriesCollection: UICollectionView,UICollectionViewDataSource,UICollectionViewDelegate {



    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }



    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        //horizontal items number
        return imageData.count //this should be the subcategories count
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "subcategoriesCell", for: indexPath) as! SubcategoriesCollectionCell

        cell.subcategoryImg.image = imageData[indexPath.row]
        cell.subcategoryName.text = imageName[indexPath.row]


        return cell
    }
}
```

and here my table view class

```
class HomeTable: UITableView,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource{

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        self.delegate = self
        self.dataSource = self
    }
    let cellSpacingHeight: CGFloat = 0
    func numberOfSections(in tableView:UITableView)->Int{

        return category.count
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView,numberOfRowsInSection section:Int)->Int{
        return 1
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return cellSpacingHeight
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
        let headerView = UIView()
        headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        return headerView
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView,cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)->UITableViewCell{
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CategoryCell") as! CategoryCell
        //setting the category title here
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to redesign your tableviewCell add a label and under label add collectionview once you are adding data into collectionview you just need to add category name to the label and all subcategories will be in collectionview under that label like.

Hope you understand what i tried to tell you if not feel free to ask.

Thanks