# how to upload Image on server using Alamofire with parameters

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, alamofireimage, alamofire-upload

I am uploading Image on server using Alamofire only (without using any model class). I've tried multiple link for e.g [upload image to server using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519829/upload-image-to-server-using-alamofire) in every Link I stuck on this issue " **Cannot invoke 'data' with an argument list of type '(using: String.Encoding)'** " I do not understand what went wrong. kindly let me know below is my code:

Required parameters are

```
 /*
name:test, 
description:testing testing, 
image:**filetype** , 
user_id:63, 
add_by:63
*/
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Don;t convert `value` to `AnyObject`. Instead just check that `value.data(...)` is not `nil`.

Comment: code do not failed to run ...as it gives me red suggestion to change it into anyobject

Comment: It's just a suggestion, not and automatic fix. In this case, it's not what you want.

Comment: without doing so..code does not run..while run its gives build failed

Comment: What error are you getting? (You probably need to check for `nil` so that code compiles.)

Answer (score 0):

You should downcast the value as a string and not as anyobect.