# How does Alamofire "upload" images from Swift to a backend?

Tags: swift, django, google-cloud-storage, alamofire, alamofireimage

I am trying to upload images from Swift to my Django backend so that I can store them in Google Cloud Storage and access them as "foreign keys" in my database models in django. There seems to be a built in library to bridge Django models and Google Storage https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html.

Reference [upload image to server using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519829/upload-image-to-server-using-alamofire).
Before sending an image to the backend, the image is converted into a UIImageJPEGRepresentation. How exactly is Alamofire then sending the image via "multipartFormData"? Is it simply sending the raw UIImageJPEGRepresentation as a string?

I am asking this because I need to somehow convert this image data I receive in my backend and store it in a Django model and simultaneously upload it to Google Storage.

From the documentation:

```
>>> class Resume(models.Model):
...     pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdfs')
...     photos = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos')
```

To store a local file to cloud storage and at the same time in a model field:

```
>>> obj1.pdf.save('django_test.txt', ContentFile('content'))
>>> obj1.pdf
<FieldFile: tests/django_test.txt>
```

Would something like this work for an image sent from Alamofire?

```
>>> obj1.photos.save(<Insert whatever was sent from Alamofire>)
```

If so, how do you access the data sent from Alamofire?