# image not upload to server using multipartformdata in Alamofire

Tags: swift, uiimageview, alamofire

I have tried so many method but image is not uploading to server

```
var params = [String:AnyObject]()
        params["profile_picture"] = displayPhoto.image
        AF.upload(
                
                 multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in

                    for (key, value) in params {
                    multipartFormData.append((value as! String).data(using:String.Encoding.utf8)!, withName: key)
                           }
                    if let imageData = self.displayPhoto.image?.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.5) {
                     multipartFormData.append(imageData, withName: "profile_picture", fileName: "file.jpeg", mimeType: "image/jpeg")
                           }

 }, to: "http://ms.XXX/regester",usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),method: .post,headers: nil).responseJSON{
                                   response in
                                   switch response.result {
                                   case .success:
                                    print(response)
                                     let vc = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: Bundle.main).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "homeVC") as? HomeVC
                                            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc!, animated: true)
                                          break
                                   case .failure(let error):
                                       print(error)
                                       break
                                   }}
```

I have tried many stackoverflows method but unable to solve the issue **please clarify my error**
im selecting image from the gallery

Comment: Can you attach the error? And it would be nice to know what exactly is the displayPhoto property.

Comment: looks wrong with pass the data in param, check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40521003/4919289

Comment: don't you crash on `value as! String`?

Comment: @ŁukaszŁabuński Could not cast value of type 'UIImage' ) to 'NSString'