# How to send an array of json as value for multipart/form-data content type?

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, alamofire

Guys I need to send parameters described in the image value where content type is `multipart/form-data`. Im having difficulty in sending only `package_json` parameter.

[image]

The problem is I don't know how do I send multiple `package_json` values as parameter? I can send one value like this:

```
let param = [
       "outletId : "1",
       "vehicleId" : "1",
       "instructions" : tvInstructions.text,
       "package_json" : "[{\"packageId\":\"1\"}]",
       "addressId" : "1"
]
```

Above i'm able to send `package_json` = `[{"packageId": 1}]` as `String` as my function below sends parameters as `[String : String]` and images of Data type as `[String : Any]`. Im having problem sending multiple values in `package_json`. For eg. something like this: `[{"packageId": 1}, {"packageId": 2}, {"packageId": 3}]` and so on. Here's the function that i'm using to send parameters:

```
 func postrequest(_ request: String, onPath imagesData:[Data]?,_ imageName : String, andParameter parameters: [String:String]?, withCompletion response: @escaping serviceCompletion) {
        let headers: HTTPHeaders
        headers = ["Content-type": "multipart/form-data"]
        AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multiPart in
            if let allParams = parameters {
                for (key, value) in allParams {
                    multiPart.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
                }
            }
            for imageData in imagesData ?? [] {
                multiPart.append(imageData, withName: "\(imageName)", fileName: "file.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
            }
        }, to: request, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(),
           method: .post,

           headers:  headers).response { (res) in
            if((res.error == nil)){
                do {
                    response(res.data,res.error)
                }
            }
            else{
                // hideHud()
                response(res.data,res.error)
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried to convert function to send `[String: Any]` data but found out we can only send as `[String : String]` along with images as `[String : Any]`.

I just want to know if there is any way to modify `"package_json" : "[{\"packageId\":\"1\"}]"` so I can send `[{"packageId": 1}, {"packageId": 2}, {"packageId": 3}]`?

Just in case, this is how im calling above function and sending parameters:

```
 func sendData() {
        
        let param = [
            "outletId" : "1",
            "vehicleId" : "1",
            "instructions" : tvInstructions.text,
            "package_json" : "[{\"packageId\":\"1\"}]",
            "addressId" : "1"
        ]

        ApiNetworkManager.shared.postrequest(Api.completeUrl, onPath: [], "", andParameter: param) { (response, err) in
            ApiNetworkManager.shared.hideHud()
            debugPrint(param)
            let json = JSON.init(response!)
            debugPrint(json)
            if err == nil {
                if err == nil && response != nil {
                    if json.dictionaryValue["success"]?.stringValue == "1" {
                        //Add your code here
                    }
                    else{
                        let message = json.dictionaryValue["message"]?.stringValue
                        self.showAlert(Message: message ?? "Error")
                    }

                } else {
//                        hideHud()
                    print(err?.localizedDescription as Any)
                    let message = json.dictionaryValue["message"]?.stringValue
                    self.showAlert(Message: message ?? "Error")
                }
            }
            else{
                ApiNetworkManager.shared.hideHud()
                let message = err?.localizedDescription
                self.showAlert(Message: message ?? "Error")
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519829/upload-image-to-server-using-alamofire

Comment: Does this answer your question? [upload image to server using Alamofire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40519829/upload-image-to-server-using-alamofire)

Comment: Not really, my function does send image, I want to send “package-json” as “Any type”. With these I can send other parameters as string only and image as Data, but how to send this: “ [{"packageId": 1}, {"packageId": 1}] ”?

Comment: So is your problem "how to send paramters with multi-part request", or "how to handle multiple parameters with the same name"? they are 2 entirely different questions

Comment: @jjquirckart I edited my question so you can understand what I mean.

Comment: @Cora I edited my question, im not asking to send image, im asking to send this array which can be of any length: [{"packageId": 1}, {"packageId": 2}, {"packageId": 3}]

Comment: I don’t see why you’d have a problem sending a json as string.

Comment: @Cora I can send 1 value like this: "[{\"packageId\":\"1\"}]" but how to send lets say "[{\"packageId\":\"1\"},{\"packageId\":\"2\"} ]" or maybe package id upto 10, right now I'm sending hard coded values for 1 or 2 but I want to send dynamic values which can be 2, 3 or multiple values from 1 to 10, how do I append those values in some array of json in this format: "[{\"packageId\":\"1\"},{\"packageId\":\"2\"} .....{\"packageId\":\"n\"} ]" ?